# Prove or give a counterexample for the following statement on strongly convergence on a dense subset

Tags: calculus

I have a tough time to figure out this assertion.

> For any $f \in C^{\infty}_c ((0,1))$. We also let $\{f_n\}$ be sequence of
>   functions on $L^2((0,1)).$ As $n$ goes to infinity, if $\langle f, f_n\rangle \to 0$ strongly , then
>   we will have $\langle w, f_n\rangle \to 0$ strongly for any $w \in
> L^2((0,1)).$

Where $\langle f,g \rangle$ is defined as $$\int_0^1 fg dx.$$

Here is my proof:

Since $ C^{\infty}_c ((0,1))$ is dense on $L^{2}((0,1)),$ for every function $g$ in $L^2((0,1)),$ we will have $\|g-f\|_{L^2((0,1))} < \epsilon,$ for some $f \in C^{\infty}_c ((0,1))$ and some $\epsilon >0.$

It means that

$$\int_0^1 g^2 + f^2 - 2fg  dx < \epsilon$$

We know that $$\int_0^1 ff_n dx <\epsilon.$$

We want to show that $$\int_0^1  f_ng dx < \epsilon'.$$

Then I have no idea about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Start with
$$\langle w,f_n\rangle=\langle w-g+g,f_n\rangle=\langle w-g,f_n\rangle+\langle g,f_n\rangle\leq \|w-g\|\|f_n\|+\langle g,f_n\rangle.$$
Now the second term goes to zero, and the the first term of the product in the first term is small. Argue why $\|f_n\|$ cannot diverge and you are done.

If you need further hints, just tell me.

Comment: The reason why $\|f_n\|$ cannot diverge is that $f_n$ is in the $L^2$ space, right?

Comment: You can actually **choose** them so that they don't diverge.